# Embed R code into BASH unix script

Tags: r, bash, unix

We know that we can embed AWK or SED directly into a BASH script by 
awk { ....}
. I wanted to do something similar to R such as 
mybashscript.sh
R { .... }

without having to create a .R file and calling the .R file from bash using Rscript myRscript.R

Is there a way to do this. I have searched everywhere but was not able to find an answer. Please help.

Comment: There's also Dirk Eddelbeutel's littler program: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/

Answer (score 2):

Bash is able to execute a statement from an arbitrary scripting language. It is in the form `VARIABLE_NAME=$(INTERPRETER -c "EMBEDDED CODE")`. In the case of R `INTERPRETER -c` would be replaced with `R --arch i386 -q --slave -e`. The `--arch` option can be any supported architecture such as i386 or x64, `-q` keep the interpreter from printing start-up info and `--slave` keeps the output as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily embed R code directly into a bash script using the `Rscript` command, and specifically, with regards to your question, the `-e expr` construction. Check `man Rscript`.

An example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a bash script"
echo "Running R code..."

Rscript -e 'cat("hello world")'
```

Comment: Thanks Micah, this is such an elegant solution, I also found that we can embed multi line code using a semicolon such as Rscript -e 'x=c(1,2,3,4); print(x)'